# bigquery concat array of bool values

Tags: google-bigquery

Trying to run this query and having an issue with the "granted" field:

```
SELECT 

ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT permission FROM t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo), ',') permissions,
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT granted FROM t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo), ',') granted,
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT resource FROM t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo), ',') resource,

protopayload_auditlog.requestMetadata.callerSuppliedUserAgent AS agent,
timestamp,
severity,
resource.labels.bucket_name as name_of_bucket,
protopayload_auditlog.authenticationInfo.principalEmail

FROM 
`mytable` t
```

Granted is boolean not string and im getting this error:

```
No matching signature for function ARRAY_TO_STRING for argument types: ARRAY, STRING. Supported signatures: ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY, STRING, [STRING]); ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY, BYTES, [BYTES]) at [6:1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should CAST Boolean to STRING as in below example

```
ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(SELECT CAST(granted AS STRING) FROM t.protopayload_auditlog.authorizationInfo), ',') granted,
```